# How to create a colored font in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am making a canvas with black background. These canvas have some rectangles and text attached to it. I wanted to use white color of text fonts instead of default black. But since font didn't have an option of using color i am not sure what to be done to change color of text.
I am creating text like this.

```
.c create text $i $j -text "($i,$j)" -anchor ne -font fontTEMP_varwidth

font create fontTEMP_varwidth \
   -family {comic sans ms} \
      -size -10 \
         -weight bold \
         -col
            -slant roman
```

Comment: Looks like it's a `text` item type on a canvas. Those support colouring via `-fill`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts themselves aren't coloured (Tk considers them to be purely about the shape of the letters), but you can set the colour to use elsewhere. In particular, the [canvas widget's text item type](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M156) supports the standard `-fill` option, which is the colour used to render the text in the item:

```
.c create text $i $j -text "($i,$j)" -anchor ne -font fontTEMP_varwidth -fill red
```

If you were using a text widget, you'd usually set the colour along with the font on the tag applied to the text. (Or you'd set the default for the entire widget.)